# Using a local name in a `use` declaration

Tags: rust

Is there any way to refer to a local name in a `use` declaration?

```
pub mod a {
    pub mod b {
        pub mod c {

        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use a::b;

    use a::b::c; //< This compiles, but is kind of roundabout,
        // considering that I have already imported `b` into scope.

    use b::c; //< This fails to compile!

    use self::b::c; //< This also fails to compile
}
```

I am currently working on a procedural macro that generates code, and in an effort to maintain hygiene, I want to add a `use` declaration for a locally imported crate (`extern crate blah` in that case). However, I can't seem to be able to refer to that name in the `use` declaration.

Is it somehow possible? Where are the rules for `use` name resolution spelled out in detail?

---

I put a [more elaborate/motivating example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=pub%20mod%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20mod%20b%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20trait%20Trait%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20trait_fn(%26self)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Struct%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20a%3A%3Ab%3A%3ATrait%20for%20Struct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20trait_fn(%26self)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20use%20a%3A%3Ab%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20s%20%3D%20Struct%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20use%20a%3A%3Ab%3A%3ATrait%3B%20%2F%2F%3C%20Avoid%20naming%20%60a%60%20here.%20%60self%3A%3Ab%3A%3ATrait%60%20would%20be%20perfect%2C%20but%20doesn%27t%20work%0A%20%20%20%20s.trait_fn()%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0) wherein I use `use` to bring a trait into scope up on the playground.

Comment: `use self::b::c::Foo;` would work *outside* a function (at module scope).

Comment: It sure does. So I feel it shouldn't be too much to ask to achieve a similar thing in a nested scope, to avoid messing around in the module scope :/

Comment: I am afraid that it may be that the use of `self` at module scope is special cased. Seeing as `self` is used for methods, not all nested scopes could benefit from it anyway... Not sure if this is solvable due to keyword reuse.

Comment: Gah, that's not ideal. I have always found it confusing that `use` resolves names from ... some "top level" scope. Module? I would have expected the same rules for name resolution as in the rest of my code :/ And perhaps a leading `::` to get to the top level scope?

Comment: `use` resolves from crate level by default; you can use `self` and `super` to alter this behavior. The idea was, I think, that it makes reasoning about `use` non-local and eases transfer of code from module to another. I personally just find it confusing though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

When you have already imported `a::b` and want to access a trait from `c`, you can do it in the following manner:

```
pub mod a {
    pub mod b {
        pub mod c {
            pub trait Foo {}
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use a::b;

    struct Derp;

    impl b::c::Foo for Derp {}
}
```

Comment: Right, I'm looking for `use`, so I can bring a trait into scope.

Comment: So your answer is "no", then? It is not possible to refer to a local name in a `use` declaration?

Comment: Not that I know of (not in the exact way you are after), but maybe someone else knows a different way.

Comment: See my question edit for elaboration on what exactly I meant by bringing a trait into scope. Thanks anyway :)